# js file not found on Heroku

Tags: node.js, file, heroku

My socket.js file can not be found when my Node.js server runs on Heroku, however when it runs on localhost, it is found. In addition, although the app.js file is in the same directory with socket.js file, it can not be found. I've seen some posts suggesting to use

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
```

but i guess it is not the case here.

my index.html file :

```
<script src="/angular-socket-io/socket.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Amongst them, the only one couldnt be found is the second directory(/socket.js) which contains the 'socket factory'inside.
My folder tree is as follows;

```
-app
--assets
---app.js
---socket.js
```

Any help please?

Comment: Could you add how you include your socket.io code in your HTML file? I am using this code snippet `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`. Now I could add in my HTML file a file destination like `file.js` and if it is in my `public` folder, it will be found.

Comment: i added extra info. to the question @Cludch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app/assets')));` to your main code and after that you can use `<script src="/socket.js"></script>`

Comment: Did something similar to this which was to add a new folder under 'app' since saving under assets didn't work. It finally worked thank you @Cludch

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

My JavaScript file didn't initialize because of how I imported the JQuery script inside of my index.html.
If your JavaScript file that contains JQuery is not initialized. Make sure to import it with **HTTPS** not **HTTP**.

**WRONG :**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

**CORRECT :**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

This solved my problem of missing the JavaScript file on Heroku.